# iOS: Test a specific screen without going through the whole app flow

Tags: ios, testing, user-interface

In order to test some of the UI tweaks I have done on a given screen, I need to go through the whole app flow to get to that particular screen. This is quite annoying and time consuming. Are there any tools/solutions/ideas that solve this problem ? Is there any way you can test a particular screen without having to go through the whole app.

If the app is using a backend service, that means every time the app is run, a connection with the backend must be established, you have to log in, etc. This is again annoying and time consuming. The same question applies for this scenario too - is there anything that can help solve this problem, and test a particular screen, without relying on a backend connection.

I basically want to find out if other people have similar problems and what are they using to solve them.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards, then check the box (Is initial screen) from the tools on the right.

And hardcode the data if you use any.

If you are not using storyboard, then do this in your AppDelegate.

Hope that solves it for you. :)

Comment: Wow, this is very useful, didnt know about it ! thanks ! However, what is your approach for hardcoding the data ?

Comment: Depending on what values you need for this controller to work correctly, I always put it in a separate method and call it in the viewDidLoad...

Comment: Perhaps deserves the chosen answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Mr_bern suggested the approach would differ according to your usage of Storyboard or Xib.
In storyBoard you can do so by checking the checkBox "Is Initial screen" from the tools.

Incase you are using the XIB then you just go to the AppDelegate and do the following:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.myViewController;
```

please don't forget to import the corresponding ViewController in the AppDelegate and then just create a corresponding property of it and set the rootViewController.

Hope it helps..